# Does calling thread.sleep on a spark job have any issues with it?

Tags: apache-spark

If my spark job is calling `thread.sleep`on Spark driver , does this have any issues or is it perfectly fine?

Answer (score 3):

That would depend where you are calling it.
If you are calling it in the driver then it behaves the same as any other program (which might cause issues with some actions having the executors timeout).

If you are calling it in the worker then the worker would probably be killed by the resource manager for not giving a heartbeat.

Comment: you can always increase the heartbeat no?

Comment: If you can not "sleep" how can you solve a MongoDB write throttling problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you have any specific reason to call the `Thread.Sleep()` or you wanted to know whether its possible or not .
yes its possible to call `Thread.Sleep()` but depends on the scenario why you wanted to do so.There are few articles you can go through those things .[ThreadSleepexample](https://github.com/eBay/Spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/ActorWordCount.scala). Normally `Thread.sleep()` in Spark will increase the CPU overhead.